# UIPopoverController button selecting method of another ViewController but not updating its view iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, uipopovercontroller

I have a mapview that has 2 methods in it.

Method 1:

```
-(void)refreshMap{
//Refresh code here....

}
```

Method 2:

```
-(void)recenterMap{

[theMap setCenterCoordinate:theMap.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];

}
```

I have a navbar button in the mapView that when pressed presents a popOverController with 2 buttons and its actions hooked up to call the methods located in the mapView Class above

The 2 buttons in the popover when Pressed calls the 2 above methods in my MapView. I have logged the methods and they do get called by the popovers buttons but the mapView View that sits behind the popover never updates. If I call the same methods directly in the MapView i.e. not using the buttons in the popover the view updates as expected?

Example image i.e when I touch center map the ui in the bg does not update but does if I can method not from the popover but directly in the map view:

[image: mapView with Popover]

Comment: Post the code that update the view so we can help you.

Comment: @Scar I have posted the recenterMap code which works when accessed directly in theMap view controller. If I call this method from popover I get the log to say its called but the view doesnt update..

Comment: @AlexMcPherson, did you try to log `theMap` to see if it is not `nil`?

Comment: @tolgamorf the map is not nil no..

Comment: anyone I assume this should be simple....